# Cannot run ASP.net service on IIS (Windows 10) - error 404 (not found)

Tags: asp.net, iis

Here's the scenario: Windows 10, VS2015 update 3.

Create new blank 'empty' asp.net project, .NET 4.5.2, and add a dummy 'index.html'.
Run project with IIS express (the default): runs fine.

Change server to IIS: get HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error, Error Code
   0x80070021. This suggests an invalid section 'modules' in web.config. So I comment out that section and run again. That gives the 404 error.

My JavaScript is working fine on IIS, but it appears that IIS is not starting the ASP.NET service - every ajax call to the service results in error 404. So I guess there's something missing from web.config. I have this in system.servicemodel

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WebMap.WebMap">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="WebMap.IWebMap" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

and the file service1.svc consists of

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebMap.WebMap" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
```

Notes: (1) two different PC's are doing the same thing. (2) if I create a new 'WebAPI' project, rather than an 'empty' one, I get exactly the same results, except that more sections need commenting out of 'web.config'

Comment: Error `500.19` means there is an error in the Web.Config. Are the same things installed on both servers (like the IIS rewrite module, which is not installed by default)?

Comment: As mentioned already, I found (and dealt with) the meaning of 500.19. AFAIK the IIS rewrite module isn't relevant here, but if others suggest it is I will try it. Otherwise I don't wish to complicate my installation.

Comment: As you made changes to your applicationhost.config I suspect the problem is there. You mentioned that 2 PCs do the same. Have you ever changed applicationhost.config on another PC? Was IIS installed after VS?

Comment: @Yuri, I didn't change applicationhost.config on my laptop, only the desktop. IIS was installed after VS on both. Should I try to reinstall VS?

Comment: I would do reinstall VS if you cannot do aspregiis

Comment: OK, I'll try that. I'm away from home now for a week with limited internet so it'll have to wait.

Comment: @Yuri I have repaired VS with no effect. Is aspnet_regiis is relevant here? With Windows10, IIS is installed via Windows Features. Anyway I have edited my post after more experiments.

Comment: do you want to get on chat? what time?

Comment: OK, not sure what time zone you're in but between 15:00 and 18:00 GMT Wednesday would be good.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127735/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-quilkin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to what is answred here [IIS - this configuration section cannot be used at this path (configuration locking?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock)
also add HTTP activation as shown below

[image]

Comment: It was the HTTP Activation that did it in my case. Puzzled why it's not activated by automatically VS2015 for a WCF project.